# How do I start using django south database migration?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

I have recently recovered from a rather evil server crash where my hosts (hilariously) deleted the entire server in a failed rack migration. Fortunately I had taken some backups and the server is back up and running. I've been meaning to start using south and feel that this could potentially help me perform upgrades in the future.

Currently I develop on a local machine and then push changes out to my production server. Previously this had been a pretty painful experience, but south looks like it could make it all easier.

As it stands, my development machine has some changes which haven't made it as far as the production server but I'd like to roll those changes out. Both development machine and production server are linked to a subversion account which stores all the code.

### Questions..

1. How do I go about installing south on both machines.
2. How do I use it to migrate changes on the dev machine to production.

### Quick example..

For example, would this work:

1. Install south for each app on the production server and create initial migrations.
2. Commit changes to svn
3. Dump database from production server
4. Check out latest changes from svn on local machine.

At this point the dev machine should match the production server right? Now to update my changes from dev to production server:

1. Copy my local changes over the checked out copy on the dev machine and use south to create a migration for my updates.
2. Commit changes to .svn
3. Run the migration on the production server to update the changes to the schema and migrate data to the new database

Will this work?

Comment: Made some corrections to make this more suitable for SO - I'll raise a seperate query for the third question I had.

Answer (score 3):

1. take a look at
   http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app
2. other than that it fairly simple:

   on dev:

   - modify models
   - ./manage.py schemamigration app --auto
   - ./manage.py migrate
   - check thigs work
   - commit

   on prod:

   - checkout
   - ./manage.py migrate
   - restart server